# What is the correct recursive way to generate a tree of teams from a tree of people?

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a Person object which has the following properties

```
public class Person
{
   public string FirstName;
   public string LastName;
   public string TeamName;
   public Person Manager;
   public IEnumerable<Person> DirectReports;
}
```

so given that i could create a hierarchy of People by recursively looping through each person's directreports and their directreports, etc like something like this:

```
foreach (Person direct in person.DirectReports)
{
       foreach (Person subDirect in direct.DirectReports)
       {
            etc . . .
       }
}
```

From this data, I am now trying to convert to generate a hierarchy of Teams so i have something like this:

```
 public class Team
 {
    public string TeamName;
    public IEnumerable<Team> SubTeams;
    public IEnumerable<Person> PeopleInTeam;
}
```

Note that if the a person's directReports may or may not have the same TeamName so the number of level of people in Person hierarchy is not necessarily the same number of Levels in the team hierarchy

for example:

```
| Person| ParentPerson | TeamName   |  
| Bill  |  ""          | Management |  
| Joe   |  Bill        | Management |  
| Scott |  Bill        | Marketing  |  
| Jim   |  Bill        | Technology |   
| Mark  |  Scott       | Marketing  |
| Bob   |  Joe         | Marketing  |
```

so after the conversion, I would have a team called "Management" with 2 people in it.  It would have 2 items in the SubTeams array (one for Marketing and one for Technology).  each of those teams would have no entries in the SubTeams array

What would be the best way to efficient take this hierarchy of people and convert it into a hierarchy of Teams?   I have listed the code below but it seems to be failing. Right now, I am looping through each person and their direct reports and creating a dictionary of teams and adding each person at a time onto a team but it seems quite slow.  here is an example ..

```
 Dictionary<string, Team> teams = new Dictionary<string, Team>();

 foreach (Person direct in person.DirectReports)
 {
       if (teams.ContainsKey(direct.TeamName)
       {
              var team = teams[direct.TeamName];
              team.People.Add(direct);
       }
       else
       {
            var team = new Team(){TeamName = direct.TeamName};
            team.People.Add(direct);
            teams[direct.TeamName] = team;
       }
       foreach (Person subDirect in direct.DirectReports)
       {
            etc . . .
       }
}
```

Comment: Before you worry about finding a faster way, you need to have some way you're using now that is too slow with which to compare it. What are you using now?

Comment: @KenWhite - i have updated the question with what i am doing now.  I would appreciate it if you would give me 2 minutes to respond and update the question before trying to have the question closed.  That seems like a reasonable thing to respond to your comment

Comment: Are you actually indefinitely nesting foreach-loops, or is that your way of describing a recursive method?

Comment: I'm assuming this is the case, but can the relationships between People and their DirectReports also be mapped to a tree? In other words, could you have a B be a DirectReport of A, C be a DirectReport of B, and A be a DirectReport of C (e.g. a cycle)?

Comment: @roliu - no, you can not have a circular reference in terms of direct reports

Comment: Well the code you have there seems asymptotically optimal considering it takes `O(n)` where `n` is the total number of `People` (it's equivalent to a preorder traversal). Also, as SimonSvensson mentioned, your implementation doesn't actually seem to be complete. Did you just keep adding `foreach` loops because the depth of your `People` tree is some small number (e.g. 2 or 3)? Or have you not finished your implementation yet?

Comment: @roliu - up until now i have only seen 4 level so i am creating these nested loops.  I am sure i could do it more elegantly with some recursion but i was just trying to get it to work . .

Comment: @leora Ah so your question is just how to make the code cleaner. The only thing I think is still missing is how you construct the Team tree (i.e. how do you tell if one Team is a SubTeam of a another?). Do you construct this somewhere else, and this function will take it as "pre-constructed" (i.e. the teams in the Dictionary are already related to each other via SubTeams)? Oh, also, do you have the flat list of all of the `Person`s, or do you only have a list of the `Person`s "at the top"?

Comment: @roliu - no, i do not have a preconstructed list of team hierarchy.  That is what i am trying to do on the fly but maybe there is a flaw in my logic.  A team is a subteam of another if there is a person in that team that has a parent person with a different team name.  So in my example Marketing is a sub team of Management

Comment: Actually, I'm a bit confused. I see in your code that you add a new `Team` if it's not in the `Dictionary`. But... when do you relate the `Team`s to one another (i.e. update the `SubTeam` property)?

Comment: In your model, is it possible that if another entry existed (e.g. Mark in Marketing), could he report to Joe? Just trying to understand the complexity of the model you're coping with.

Comment: @M. Babcock - i have added Mark to my question so hopefully that helps.  To specific, he could report to Joe.

Comment: Also, would you mind posting your physical model for better visibility into the relationships between these entities rather than attempting to guess the right answer based on your code samples and examples.

Comment: @M. Babcock - I don't understand your comment.  The code at the top of the question defines the objects and the relationships between the objects (TeamName is just a string on a Person object) as well as sample data to show examples.  What exactly are you looking for to clarify?

Comment: Those objects would presumably be derived by something already relatively flat and they themselves don't contain the reference properties (basically the IDs or other relationship properties used to build them). If you're looking for performance than you'd be better off doing so at that level... assuming it exists.

Comment: @M. Babcock - i don't follow you point.  This is the only code that there is there ..  I think you point is there is some flaw in the code above.  If so I would appreciate if you could give an example as an answer to help point in the right direction . .

Comment: Fair enough. It won't as fast as it could be but still doable.

Comment: One more question... is it fair to assume first/last name combinations are unique? The classes provided don't contain a way to uniquely identify them otherwise.

Comment: @M. Babcock - lets assume yes to make it simpler and isolate the issue at hand

Comment: Hello, you accepted an answer already but check [mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074270/what-is-the-correct-recursive-way-to-generate-a-tree-of-teams-from-a-tree-of-peo/19088616#19088616) bellow - your situation is a very fun real-life problem so I couldn't resist to try it :) and I think it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic solution that you can use as a framework.

It's not ideal: in particular, `Dictionary<string, string>` isn't a good data structure, since we just end up looping through all the values anyway. It would be more useful to build something like a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` that maps from a department to the names of its child departments.

But it should give you a basis to work from.

```
void Main()
{
    var bill = new Person { FirstName = "Bill", TeamName = "Management" };
    var joe = new Person { FirstName = "Joe", Manager = bill, TeamName = "Management" };
    var scott = new Person { FirstName = "Scott", Manager = bill, TeamName = "Marketing" };
    var jim = new Person { FirstName = "Jim", Manager = bill, TeamName = "Technology" };
    var mark = new Person { FirstName = "Mark", Manager = scott, TeamName = "Marketing" };
    var bob = new Person { FirstName = "Bob", Manager = joe, TeamName = "Marketing" };
    var ted = new Person { FirstName = "Ted", Manager = jim, TeamName = "IT Support" };

    var people = new[] { bill, joe, scott, jim, mark, bob, ted };

    var teamParents = people.Select (p => new { Team = p.TeamName, ParentTeam = p.Manager == null ? null : p.Manager.TeamName });

    // don't let a team be its own parent
    teamParents = teamParents.Where (p => !p.Team.Equals(p.ParentTeam));

    // make sure they're all unique
    teamParents = teamParents.Distinct();

    // put it in a dictionary
    var teamHierarchy = teamParents.ToDictionary (p => p.Team, q => q.ParentTeam);

    foreach (string root in teamHierarchy.Where (h => h.Value == null).Select (h => h.Key))
    {    
        PrintSubteams(teamHierarchy, 0, root);
    }    
}

private void PrintSubteams(Dictionary<string, string> hierarchy, int level, string root)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("    ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine(root);

    foreach (string child in hierarchy.Where (h => h.Value == root).Select(h => h.Key))
    {
        PrintSubteams(hierarchy, level + 1, child);
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public string TeamName;
    public Person Manager;
    public IEnumerable<Person> DirectReports;
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Management
    Marketing
    Technology
        IT Support
```

(I added the IT Support team to make it a little more interesting.)

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a list of the people at the top of the tree then we can try this:

```
public void ConstructTeams(IEnumerable<Person> topPeople,
    Dictionary<string, Team> teamsByName)
{
    foreach (Person person in topPeople)
    {
        // Add person to their team. Create one if it doesn't exist
        Team matchingTeam;
        if (teamsByName.TryGetValue(person.TeamName, out matchingTeam))
        {
            matchingTeam.PeopleInTeam.Add(person);
        }
        else
        {
            // Create a new team and update its parent team
            matchingTeam = new Team
            {
                TeamName = direct.TeamName
                PeopleInTeam = new List<Person>()
            };
            matchingTeam.PeopleInTeam.Add(person);
            teamsByName.Add(matchingTeam.TeamName, matchingTeam);

            // The manager's team should already exist because we traversing the
            // Person tree/forest from the roots to the leaves
            if (person.Manager != null)
            {
                teamsByName[person.Manager.TeamName].SubTeams.Add(matchingTeam);
            }
        }

        // Recursively fill in the direct reports
        ConstructTeams(person.DirectReports, teamsByName);
    }
}
```

Here's a solution if you have a flat list of all the people.

```
public IEnumerable<Team> ConstructTeams(IEnumerable<Person> allPeople)
{
    var teams = allPeople.GroupBy(person => person.TeamName)
        .Select(grouping => new Team
        {
            TeamName = grouping.Key,
            // I think this works, but IGroupings are weird and I don't
            // have a compiler with me
            PeopleInTeam = grouping.ToList()
        });

    // Set SubTeams
    // Group the teams by parent team. We assumed that
    // no team has two parent teams
    var teamsGroupedByParentTeam = teams
        .GroupBy(team => team.PeopleInTeam.First().TeamName);

    foreach (var groupOfTeams in teamsGroupedByParentTeam)
    {
        var parentTeam = teams.Single(team => team.TeamName == teamsGroupedByParentTeam.TeamName);
        parentTeam.SubTeams = groupOfTeams.ToList();
    }

    return teams;
}
```

Comment: Upfront i have a list of all people but they are bucketed into the heirachies (DirectReports) so it would be very easily to convert that into one single Ienumerable<Person> . .  (not sure if that helps clarify your suggestion).  The one issue with your answer is i don't see where it creates relationships between a team and its parent team

Comment: @leora I'm confused. Didn't I state clearly that I have no idea how to relate a team to its parent team? You didn't specify what the logic is in your original question. Did you? Where?
If you already have them organized in a hierarchy then the first set of code is more efficient. Obviously you can flatten the hierarchy and use the second method, but it will slow down the performance of your code. I would also argue it's not the most maintainable thing to swap between a Tree of people versus a flat list. If you use one representation through all of your code, then stick with that representation

Comment: The way to relate a team to a parent team must be calculated from people.  A person knows his direct reports and a person also knows his parent Person. (just realized i missed that property on Person in the original question which i am really pissed about as I think that is what is causing some confusion but i have updated now) So starting with a person who has a Team Name, walking the tree of people up the chain until you find a person that has a different team than the current team and that indicates the parent team of that team.  Does that make sense

Comment: @leora What happens if two people on the same team have different bosses on different teams? So A, B are on Team Foo. A's boss C is on Team Bar and B's boss D is on Team Baz. Is Foo a SubTeam of both Bar and Baz?

Comment: good question.  let me see if that ever actually happens. If i can't find an example of that, i think better to simply and assume that there will never happen and all teams will only have one parent team

Comment: i have confirmed that there are no examples of this so lets assume a team only has a single parent team so i will be a clean heirarchy